# Pronouncing words with the letter "d" followed by the letter "r" - Podría

Tags: pronunciación

I have no problem pronouncing the letter **d** correctly in Spanish except when it's followed by the letter **r** .

For example, in the words `podría` or `Madrid`.  It's a challenge for my whole vocal system.

Are there any websites to help with the more challenging aspect of getting the spanish accent correct?

For the most part when I speak people don't think Spanish is my second language but it's this one thing I am really struggling with.

Looking for websites!

Answer (score 2):

When /d/ is followed by /r/, most times /d/ is pronounced [ð], i.e. as the 'th' in "mother". Would this be easier for you?

Comment: absolutely, i pronounce the d as a "th" in this sense.  It's getting to the "r" sound after the "th" sound that sounds very gringo.

Comment: was wondering if there are any special tongue positioning i should be aware of??

Comment: http://www.fluentin3months.com/roll-your-r/